# Typescript - default generic to property of another generic

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is it possible to default a generic type to a property of another generic type?

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```js
function example<T = any, R = T["Property"]>(arg: T) => {}; // Type '"Property"' cannot be used to index type 'T'.

interface HasProperty {
  Property: ArbitraryType;
}

example(arg /* HasProperty */); // T = HasProperty, R = ArbitraryType
example<HasProperty, SomeOtherType>(arg /* HasProperty */); // T = HasProperty, R = SomeOtherType
```

Comment: `T extends { Property: any }`

Answer (score 0):

There's no guarantee that `T` has a `"Property"` attribute, so you should tell typescript that it must have it via the [`extends` generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints):

```
function example<T extends {Property: any} = any, R = T["Property"]>(arg: T) {}
```